# Quick and easy way to get category name from ID

Tags: categories, control-panel

We've inherited a site that has hundreds of categories in a large number of groups.

We're working on the templates and many times need to see what a category ID actually is and *where* it is. So far it's kind of cumbersome to trawl through all the groups every time looking for each one.... is there a plug for the CP that can list all the Categories outside of their groups in sequential order?

What's the best way of quickly matching these IDs to the cat name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this free extension from the mighty Low!

http://gotolow.com/addons/low-seg2cat/docs

> Working with categories? Then you need Low Seg2Cat. This extension
>   will give you information about categories present in the URI, in the
>   form of early parsed global variables. No more PHP in your templates
>   just to retrieve a category ID, no more awkward category keyword
>   identifier in your URIs, all the category info you need comes straight
>   from your segments. Oh, and it’s free.

Comment: Happy to help :)